# Saving ENUMs in C# and Loading it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums

Im trying to save some enums in my code. Saving and converting to the string is going well. But with the loading there r some problems. I mean. I just cant load it). Im doing all that in unity. I  thought to convert enum to string and after convert it back. Conversion to string works fine. But what happens with back-convestion i dont know.  Thanks.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {
public static GameControl control;
public float health;
public float experience;
public string stateString;
public enum State { start_0, start_1, start_3, start_4 };
public State myState;

void Awake () {
    if(control == null)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        control = this;
    }
    else if(control != this)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
public void Save()
{   
    stateString = myState.ToString();  //Converts ENUM to STRING
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + 
    "/playerInfo.dat");

    PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
    data.health = health;
    data.experience = experience;
    data.stateString = stateString;

    bf.Serialize(file, data);
    file.Close();   

}
public void Load()
{
    if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
    {   
        State loadedState = (State) Enum.Parse(typeof(State), stateString);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + 
    "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
        PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();

        health = data.health;
        experience = data.experience;
        stateString = data.stateString;
      }
  }

 }
 [Serializable]
 class PlayerData
 {
 public float health;
 public float experience;
 public string stateString;
 public enum State { start_0, start_1, start_3, start_4 };
 public State myState;
 }
```

Comment: *"I just cant load it"* is not a proper description - what exactly happens? What do you see when debugging this code?

Comment: Hello. Well theoreticaly it just must be converting back to enum and load the state. But actually nothing happens. No errors or something. ints and string r saving and loading normaly. Not enums though.

Comment: What does *"nothing happens"* mean? What is the state/value of the enum? It has to be *something*. And once again - what do you see when you debug this code? (values of the string, enum etc.)

Comment: by the way, **where** is your `Load` method even trying to assign the value of `myState`?

Comment: Sorry im quite noob so my answers r dull. 
Well for example when im converting - enum State = start_0 to string  and i receive a string = start_0. It is saving perfectly. After that i must to take start_0 and convert it back to Enum.

Comment: BTW thank u) while answering to you i discovered the problem. Indeed it was the thing with asigning saved/loaded variables.  In general the code works fine.

Comment: your parse is ok, where you have the problem?

Comment: You know that internally `enum` is an integer, right? Just save it's `(int)` value and then `(State)` it back when read from the datafile.

Comment: Actualy i encountered another problem. During the launch i can save and load it. But when i restartin the game, all saved data is lost and i quite dont get why it happens.